# How to "merge" or "transform" JSON documents in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: json, database, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm setting up a Chatbot with the Microsoft Bot Framework and Azure. I want to save my "UserState" in a database in order to easily analyze the user data. I managed to save my userState in form of JSON documents in Azure Cosmos DB.

The problem is that each interaction with the bot creates a new "document" in a "collection" in Cosmos DB.

How can I easily merge the data (data structure is consistent) and in the best case have the data in some kind of table? The tool I want to use for analyzing requires .txt or .csv files.

[image]

This is a snippet of the JSON file which stores the user data.

```
{
    "id": "emulator*2fusers*2f9321b527-4699-4b4a-8d9d-9cd9fa8f1967*2f",
    "realId": "emulator/users/9321b527-4699-4b4a-8d9d-9cd9fa8f1967/",
    "document": {
        "userData": {
            "name": "value",
            "age": 18,
            "gender": "value",
            "education": "value",
            "major": "value"
        },
        "userDataExtended": {
            "roundCounter": 3,
            "choices": [
                "A",
                "A",
                "B"
            ],
        },
    "_rid": "0k5YAPBrVaknAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/0k5YAA==/colls/0k5YAPBrVak=/docs/0k5YAPBrVaknAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"ac009377-0000-0000-0000-5c59c5610000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1549387105
}
```

In the best case I want to have the data in a table structure with columns "name", "age", etc. and each user (document) as a row.

Thank you!

Comment: It should not be doing that at all. It should be storing state across turns using a consistent `id` for the documents that is tied to the identifiers of the channel and conversation or user. Your screenshot does not show enough information. I need to see more than one document. Can you maybe copy/paste a few of the documents into a public Gist so I can look them over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things in your questions and I'll address them all separately.

#### Expanding on Drew's comment:

You have multiple documents being created because you're running the bot through emulator. Each time emulator restarts, it creates a new User ID and therefore a new document for the user and also one for that user's conversation. You will not have this issue if you use a channel other than emulator, provided that the User ID remains consistent.

#### Regarding merging documents:

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you might be able to use [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query) to accomplish what you need. Just click "New SQL Query". For example, running `SELECT * FROM c` merges all of the documents into a single output.

[image]

#### Regarding text/csv files:

I'm not sure what your tool is, but if it can handle JSON, then the above might work for you. If not, you can implement custom middleware to get the txt/csv output you're looking for. [Here's a sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/d909c0853c36bc691a3c27ee65b389cee9bb59fb/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.logger) that shows something relatively similar. There isn't an equivalent example in C#, but you can still [implement your own middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to do the same thing.

#### Regarding Tables:

If you're **really** looking for Table Storage, [it was supported in V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) bots, but replaced by blob storage in V4. You could write your bot in V3. Similar to what Jay said, you might still be able to use a trigger function to send it to table storage, but then you're storing the data twice.

#### Regarding Analysis

If all you're really looking for is analysis, [Application Insights/Bot Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-analytics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) may be what you need, although I don't believe it will provide the detail you're looking for.

Comment: **Multiple Documents**
Also in my "production" environment I will have different user IDs to identify each of the users. But the document merge via SQL query worked well and is exactly what I was looking for (sorry I'm really unexperienced). 

**CSV/Table**
I found a [tool](https://json-csv.com/) that easily converts the single output into rows and colums just the way I wanted.

Therefore, the topic can be closed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mdrichardson, Hi looks like the link for 'Here's a sample' is no longer existed,could you please provide another sample link? Regarding to text/csv file, are you suggesting we need to convert them to JSON data/file first, then send to cosmos db to handle? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @FRANZKAFKA, Hi could you please share your merge via SQL query? The tool you provided looks like converting Json file to csv, is there any way we can directly send json data to cosmos db and use SQL query to handle the merge? Thank you!

Comment: @KevDing We no longer have that sample, but I updated the link to the sample from the Git Repo History. Should work now. For text/csv, you don't need to convert them; Bot Framework SDK saves all BotState as JSON in Cosmos.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, thank you very much for sharing the link! Unfortunately I am having some trouble with reading the node.js code, do you have a similar project using .Net Core in C#? Or any API/Nuget Package that I can refer or use?

Comment: @KevDing We didn't write that sampel in C#. However, [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/d909c0853c36bc691a3c27ee65b389cee9bb59fb/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history) is the closest that we have. If you need further help, feel free to open a new Stack Overflow question after you've tried some things. We look at new tickets ever work day.

Answer (score 0):

> In the best case I want to have the data in a table structure with
>   columns "name", "age", etc. and each user (document) as a row.

Obviously,you need to use some other services to implement this requirement because the data which is collected by bot service already exists.

In my opinion, maybe the [cosmos db trigger azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) is a good option for you. The function will be triggered when any updates inflow into your cosmos db collection.

Of course you could get more explanations from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database) ,then what I want to say is that you could configure the [Cosmos db as input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2) and [Azure Blob Storage as output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) (maybe a specific csv file). In the function,you could get your desired columns with cosmos db sdk and assemble them into any format you want.